# WhoID and WhatID

Tags: whatid

what is diffrence between whoid and whatid in salesforce?

I tried reading the diffrence from sources and could not understand. PLease help me in understanding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wZlIAI, I would encourage you to research prior to posting here. If you did, please include links and do mentiuon what exactly you dont understand from them.

Comment: I like this question and I think this post is valuable especially because of the answer given. The link from the comment above doesn't have a complete and clear answer not even comparable with the answer we have here by the master @sfdcfox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WhoId represents the primary Contact or Lead associated with the Activity (Event or Task). It's "who" you're doing the Activity with, or simply, a person you're doing something with. The WhatId represents an Account, Opportunity, Case, or almost any other type of object, including custom objects. It's "what" you're you're doing, or "what" you're talking about.

As a concrete example, if I called Bob Ross and asked him if he were interested in a bunch of painting products, the WhoId would refer to a Contact "Bob Ross," while the WhatId might refer to an Opportunity "Bob's Paint Supplies." Typically, Task and Event records will be associated to both a person and a thing.

Comment: I love the example you made in this answer!!